# Flash choppy fullscreen ver 12.04

Tags: video, flash, streaming

Tried suggested fixes, including flash aid, but still 4od streamed video is choppy full screen.

This site slows up browser and plays slow video? is it the site? even typing this has slowed as the page tries to load in another tab?
http://www.channel4.com/programmes/come-dine-with-me/4od

Comment: What are your computer specifications? And what browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with choppy audio and video. I ended up downgrading to Flash player 11.1.102.63 64-bit, which you can find at [Adobe's archived flash players page](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html).